# Python if_py and VIM: exec('import re') does not work

Tags: python, vim

I have a auto-completion script that I would like to modify
to complete class names, attributes, methods, etc. In python
when i do: `re.co<TAB>` it should give me a list of matching 
methods. Problem is, I don't want to parse the `re.py` file.
I'd prefer to:

```
import re
```

and then do `dir(re)` to get the list of methods. But How???
I tried:

```
imp_obj = exec('import re')
```

and it refused to work in `if_py`! `2 + 2` works though..

Comment: Without anything special, `import re` then `re.co<C-x><C-o>` shows two candidates: `compile(pattern,flags=0)` and `copy_reg`. What exactly do you want beyond that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use the builtin `__import__` function to import the module like so:

```
imp_obj = __import__('re')
```

Your code probably does not work because `import` does not return a value that would in turn be returned by `exec('import re')`.

In general, it is a bad idea to use `exec` on text input by the user because it has a higher probability of executing arbitrary code you don't want to execute.